# Disconnect programmatically from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, disconnection

How to programmatically disconnect the user?

Here is my problem: I know that the maximum of simultaneous connection is 100 with firebase but in my application, I'm retrieving all the data from the database and then I don't need it anymore so is it possible to disconnect the phone from firebase programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking:

> FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();

is the way to [disconnect the connection from firebase programmatically](https://livinglifetechway.com/keep-your-firebase-realtime-database-connections-to-minimum/). Putting the call at the end of your onStart callback is going to be the way to go, from the [looks of it](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). Hope that helps.